# iTerm2 + Oh My ZSH strange character

Tags: terminal, oh-my-zsh

[image]

The blue characters,how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Powerline error.Chenck [powerline/fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) out.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the `agnoster` theme. If so, this is [a known issue](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1906). The fix is to checkout one of its earlier version:

```
cd ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# optional, if the install is done by curl or wget
#git pull origin master
git checkout d6a36b1 agnoster.zsh-theme
```

After rebooting the iterm, the issue should be fixed.